# How i can click on a div with role button without text? Using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This is the html code exemple:

```
<div aria-label="Continue" class="my-class" data-visualcompletion="ignore"></div>
    <div class="div1-class">
        <div class="div1-class2">
            <span class="area-span" dir="auto">
                <span class="text-span">Continue</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-class" data-visualcompletion="ignore"></div>
```

I'm trying:

```
continue = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'my-class')) )
continue.click()
```

but it doesn't work in any of the ways I tried.

Comment: try click class `text-span`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the xpaths in the browser console.
And try doing this ?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'my-class')]"));
```